# IE Error when installing jQuery Slideshow plugin on existing site

Tags: jquery, css, browser, internet-explorer-9, compatibility

This is a site specific question, so I'll most likely need help looking at the code. I am installing Jon Raasch's "Simple jQuery Slideshow Plugin" on an existing site (that I didn't build). In IE 9, 2 things are happening that don't make sense.

1. The "border-radius" CSS code isn't rendering
2. The DIV that holds the slideshow is getting pushed down by about 50px.

Can someone please take a look at the source code and tell me why the plugin is having this conflict?

http://www.indefreetest.com/proof/JamesShields/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
<td colspan="7" background="body/body_04.jpg" height="273" alt="">   
<!--jQuery Slideshow Code-->
   <div id="slideshow">.................
```

Now give "vertical-align: top;" to  which is just before your slideshow div. Please let me know is it working or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry for the late response.

It turns out I needed the infamous "position: absolute;" attribute to be attached. It aligned everything properly. But I still can't figure out why the border-radius attribute isn't rendering in IE. Any ideas?

Comment: @VisceralConcepts `border-radius` is not working with IE8, and if you are using IE9 then it will be work fine.